# String to Byte or Char* in C++

Tags: c++, memory, editing

Okay, so I'm working on a memory editor in c++, I have a list of offsets and if I predefine what to change the offset too (0x68) then it works, but I was wondering if there was a way to convert string, as in, cin >> string, and it would split the string into bytes or char*s so it could use them in the offsets? Sorry if this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::string` class has two methods that can help you:

- `c_str()`, that returns a `\0`-terminated `char*` string (AKA a "C"-style string);
- `data()`, that returns the content of the string in a `char const*`, but without `\0` termination; you have to retrieve the length separately with `length()` or `size()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call c_str() to get a raw char array representing the string data as a c string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data()` and `memcpy()` to copy all the bytes to another address, or access the bytes in the string by indexing the string object...

```
std::string x;
if (std::cin >> x) // note: read one whitespace-separated token, use getline for lines
{
    memcpy(p_dest, x.data(), x.size());  // to copy everything...
    // ...or...
    p_dest[offset] = x[i]; // copy one character, 0 <= i < x.size()
}
```